# Marketing cloud matched/Unmatched audience extract

Tags: marketing-cloud

We are using advertising studio to build audience based on data in our data extension.

We seem to have a 60% match.

The client however needs the details of the 40% of the remaining data that didn't match.

Could anyone please provide a solution of how to make an extract here.

Any possible solutions here would be fantastic.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately no, there's no way to query, filter, or extract the data. Per Marketing cloud's data privacy policy, they do NOT release the contacts who match in ad audiences. This is also true with Facebook if you use their Ads Manager platform.

I know that wasn't the answer you were looking for, but I hope it gives you clarity on this topic.